# Можно ли nuGet пакетам указать конкретные используемые сборки

Tags: c#, .net

Имею ошибку:
**Метод не найден: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()".**
Нашёл совет перейти на Newtonsoft.Json версии 6, однако другие сборки в моём проекте требуют 12ой версии и работают не корректно. Соответственно мне нужно как-то подсунуть в  System.Net.Http.Formatting использовать версию 6, а для других продолжить использовать обновляемую 12ую
(использую framework 4.6)

Comment: Что вы такое там делаете и где, что выдает такую ошибку?

Comment: В общем - wpf приложение-надстройку над приложением, конкретно при ошибке: пытаюсь установить соединение с TFS:  new VssConnection(new Uri(TfsUri), new VssCredentials())